# Trying to get my SQL data into Excel, NULL Aggregate warning and not able to connect

Tags: sql-server, excel

I've created a query that gives me exactly what I want as far as results go, Ideally I just want to create a view with this and bring it into Excel for usage.

This is the code.....

```
--Calculates the percentage split of Property Support Departments for YTD Oct/Nov/Dec
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
declare @PropApportion Table(
type varchar(50),
net money);

insert into @PropApportion
select type,Net from DB_ConsolApportionment
where type in ('PostComplete','DirectPropSupPbo','PropSupPbo')

declare @PostComplete as money
set @PostComplete =
(select net from @PropApportion where type = 'PostComplete')

declare @PropSup as money
set @PropSup =
(select net from @PropApportion where type = 'PropSupPbo')

declare @DirPropSup as money
set @DirPropSup =
(select net from @PropApportion where type = 'DirectPropSupPbo')
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select
type,
Concat,
Net,
Cast(1. * Net/ SUM(Net) OVER(PARTITION BY type)as decimal(8,3)) as '%',
round(@PostComplete * ((1. * Net/ SUM(Net) OVER(PARTITION BY type))),2) as 'PostCompleteSplit',
round(@PropSup * ((1. * Net/ SUM(Net) OVER(PARTITION BY type))),2) as 'PropSupSplit',
round(@DirPropSup * ((1. * Net/ SUM(Net) OVER(PARTITION BY type))),2) as 'DirPropSupSplit'

from 
(select
type,
Concat,
sum(-[oct-15]-[Nov-15]-[Dec-15]) as 'Net'
from DB_ConsolApportionment ca
where type = 'Sales'
and ((ca.Concat like '%Estate%'
or ca.Concat like '%Developer%')
or concat like 'Commercial')
group by concat, type
)ca

where type = 'Sales'
and ((ca.Concat like '%Estate%'
or ca.Concat like '%Developer%')
or concat like 'Commercial')

order by
case
when concat like '%Commercial%' then 1
when concat like '%EstateAgentsA%' then 2
when concat like '%EstateAgentsB%' then 3
when concat like '%DeveloperA%' then 4
when concat like '%DeveloperB%' then 5
when concat like '%DeveloperC%' then 6
end;
```

This gives me these results....

```
type    Concat        Net       %       PostCompleteSplit   PropSupSplit    DirPropSupSplit
Sales   Commercial    46366.67  0.101   3282.290000         443.220000      11857.150000
Sales   EstateAgentsA 69717.00  0.152   4935.250000         666.420000      17828.430000
Sales   EstateAgentsB 146788.94 0.321   10391.160000        1403.150000     37537.700000
Sales   DeveloperA    88731.19  0.194   6281.260000         848.180000      22690.840000
Sales   DeveloperB    50324.18  0.110   3562.440000         481.050000      12869.190000
Sales   DeveloperC    55371.69  0.121   3919.750000         529.300000      14159.960000
```

This is exactly what I need but I need to get it into a view so that I can quickly pull it into Excel.
If I paste the query directly into Excel (Data/Existing Connections etc), Initially I got the 'Null Aggregate' warning, I then added the..
    SET ANSI_WARNNINGS OFF;
to remove the warnings as I have several other views that run from the same source that don't have the problem when running from a view. Once the warning were switched off, the query wouldn't connect to the server.

Is there a better way to structure my code so I can store it as a view?
...should I use sub-queries instead of variables?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself, I'll post this anyway in case others find it useful (or if anyone has any other tips regarding my code (..would be much appreciated)).

So..subqueries instead of variables, it takes 10 secs to run but it works!

```
--Calculates the percentage split of Peterborough Property Support Departments for YTD Oct/Nov/Dec

select
top 999999999999
ca.Type,
ca.Concat,
ca.Net,
Cast(1. * ca.Net/ SUM(ca.Net) OVER(PARTITION BY ca.type)as decimal(8,3)) as '%',
round((select sum(net) from DB_ConsolApportionment where type = 'PostComplete' ) * ((1. * ca.Net/ SUM(ca.Net) OVER(PARTITION BY ca.type))),2) as 'PostCompleteSplit',
round((select sum(net) from DB_ConsolApportionment where type = 'PropSupPbo' ) * ((1. * ca.Net/ SUM(ca.Net) OVER(PARTITION BY ca.type))),2) as 'PropSupSplit',
round((select sum(net) from DB_ConsolApportionment where type = 'DirectPropSupPbo' ) * ((1. * ca.Net/ SUM(ca.Net) OVER(PARTITION BY ca.type))),2) as 'DirPropSupSplit'

from 
(select
type,
Concat,
sum(-[oct-15]-[Nov-15]-[Dec-15]) as 'Net'
from DB_ConsolApportionment ca
where type = 'Sales'
and ((Concat like '%Estate%'
or Concat like '%Developer%')
or concat like 'Commercial')
group by concat, type
)ca

where ca.Type = 'Sales'
and ((ca.Concat like '%Estate%'
or ca.Concat like '%Developer%')
or ca.concat like 'Commercial')

order by
case
when ca.Concat like '%Commercial%' then 1
when ca.Concat like '%EstatsAgentsA%' then 2
when ca.concat like '%EstateAgentsB%' then 3
when ca.concat like '%DeveloperA%' then 4
when ca.concat like '%DeveloperB%' then 5
when ca.concat like '%DeveloperC%' then 6
end;
```